# Does this diode make any sense in this circuit?

Tags: power-supply, diodes, reverse-polarity

Here is the entry stage of power circuit for an Arduino clone. Input voltage 7-12V DC, MP2307 regulates it down to 5V. Diode D1 is presumably there to protect against reversed polarity, but it will blow up in such case. Does it make any sense? Why not place it in series with `VIN`?

[image]

---

This question was bugging me enough to reach for a multimeter and investigate. The diagram is wrong. The diode is placed between `VIN` and `IN` of MP2307, as it should be. Some sloppy documentation.

Comment: Usually when doing reverse polarity protection that way, there is also a fuse before the diode. So that the fuse blows on wrong polarity, not the diode. Although I don't see a part number. Maybe it's not a standard diode but some TVS or similar drawn with the wrong symbol?

Comment: It might make perfect sense based on design specs and we don't know the design specs, not for the input voltage or the output voltage. You left out important bits of the schematic but it is a switch mode buck regulator and we don't know what the output voltage is (could be 3.3V, could be anything).

Comment: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/how-to-protect-your-circuits-using-only-a-diode/

Comment: @Klas-Kenny I checked the board with multimeter and the diagram is wrong.

Comment: @Justme In what case it would make sense? I'm adding more specs to the post.

Comment: Well if the diagram is wrong there is no hope to figure out. Do you have the part number for D1? maybe it's a zener/tvs

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio I figured it out by measuring. D1 is in a standard configuration. See my edited post.

Comment: Is there any sensible reason to keep this question from being closed?

Answer (score 2):

Typically as drawn  D1 would be a zener or avalanche diode and is used for semi-sacrificial overvoltage protection. In this case we are overcoming the reverse bias limit of a diode to perform it's function .

As comment stated you believe the documentation is wrong, in case of series diode it would protect reverse voltage , but the voltage drop and resultant power/heat dissipation is not desirable, it is more typical now to see mosfet being used in body diode conduction which has very low effective voltage drop.

Answer (score 2):

A reverse polarity protection diode is meant to be used in conjunction with a fuse, so that if power is connected backwards the diode will conduct and blow the fuse.
Sometimes this diode will be a zener or TVS (transient voltage suppressor) diode so that it also gives some protection against overvoltage, but very often is is just a plain old rectifier diode such as a 1N4007. The exact part would depend on the fuse rating, the diode should be able to easily withstand the current it would take to blow the fuse, I come across 10A to 20A fuses used like this all the time.